# Collaps all Swagger UI groups

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

Hi I create an API in C# and use SwaggerUI to test my api.
I woud know if it's possible to automatly collaps all endpoint groups in the interface

[SwaggerUI Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqw2q.png)

here is my code to generate my interface

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Services.AddControllers();

    AddCORS(builder);
    AddDatabase(builder);
    AddServices(builder);


    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        var API_NAME = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
        var xmlPath = $"{AppContext.BaseDirectory}{API_NAME}.xml";
        
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
        {
            Version = "v1",
            Title = API_NAME,
            Description = "API for Guanajuato RolePlay"
            
        });
        
        c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
    });
    


var app = builder.Build();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code.

```
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(o =>
            {
           o.DocExpansion(Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.DocExpansion.None);
            });
        }
```

it will give you result like this.

[image]